# Nested tags in BeautifulSoup - Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've looked at many examples on websites and on stackoverflow but I couldn't find a universal solution to my question. I'm dealing with a really messy website and I'd like to scrape some data. The markup looks like so:

```
...
<body>
...
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            ...
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                ...
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                        ...
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="...">Some link</a>
                                <a href="...">Some link</a>
                                <a href="...">Some link</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

The issue I'm having is that none of the elements have attributes that I can select to narrow down some scope. Inside each of the "..." there may be similar markup such as more `<a>`'s `<table>` and whatnot.

I know that `table tr table tr td a` is unique to the links I need, but how would BeautifulSoup grab those? I'm not sure how grab nested tags without doing a bunch of individual lines of code.

Any help?

Comment: I'm using python because the links that I extract will lead to huge web pages. PHP Simple HTML Dom creates a mess of over 300 mb just to parse the pages and keeps crashing. The HTML is invalid so some other ways to parse in PHP may not work. If there are any other suggestions I would appreciate it. The pages inside the links are about 10+ mb of markup (no images). That's why Simple HTML Dom goes crazy (lots of nodes).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [CSS selectors in `select`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select('table tr table tr td a')
```

---

```
In [32]: bs4.BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen('http://google.com/?hl=en').read()).select('#footer a')
Out[32]:
[<a href="/intl/en/ads/">Advertising Programs</a>,
 <a href="/services/">Business Solutions</a>,
 <a href="https://plus.google.com/116899029375914044550" rel="publisher">+Google</a>,
 <a href="/intl/en/about.html">About Google</a>,
 <a href="http://www.google.com/setprefdomain?prefdom=RU&amp;prev=http://www.google.ru/&amp;sig=0_3F2sRGWVktTCOFLA955Vr-AWlHo%3D">Google.ru</a>,
 <a href="/intl/en/policies/">Privacy &amp; Terms</a>]
```

Comment: Does that only give the first element found or does it return all of the elements?

Comment: All of them. Just like CSS.

Comment: Really more people should know about this.