# Nested Tags/Table in BeautifulSoup Python scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've pored over Google for half a day looking for the right answer to this. The closest thing I've come to is this StackOverflow post: [Nested tags in BeautifulSoup - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749354/nested-tags-in-beautifulsoup-python)

Effectively I'm scraping wait time data from a complex page with nested elements using BeautifulSoup in Python. Some of the HTML elements have classes/ids, but most do not. Looking at the DOM I can see the path to the elements I want. I've written a preliminary script that points to the right path (...I think) but the console keeps printing out an empty array. Even changing this code to print out something simple (like soup.select('body h2')) doesn't print anything. Here is my code

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.alexianbrothershealth.org/wait-times'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
wait_times = soup.select('body div div div div div div div table tbody tr td')

print wait_times
```

Any ideas what I need to change to make this work? I have many more sites to get to, so figuring out the right syntax for the .select() pointer would really be helpful. I've tried using lxml with XPath and that also prints out an empty array. The page source tells me that it's in the HTML and not loading via javascript on the client so I should be okay there.

PS I'm a newb, so any complex answer will be entirely lost on me ;)

Comment: Something like [this - BSoup select with css selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920039/beautifulsoup-how-to-select-certain-tag) maybe?

Comment: Hmm not quite. I've looked through that example before

Answer (score 0):

I don't think select is the BeautifulSoup method you're looking for. Select uses css selectors, but you're just looking for the right set of tags.

If all the times you're looking for are in 's, I'd use

```
tds = soup.find_all("td")
for cell in tds:
    children = cell.findChildren()
    ... do actual work ...
```

Alternatively, if you want to use select (which you definitely can), try removing the whole first set of tags:

```
soup.select("table tbody tr td")
```

works fine.

Comment: I've printed all td's before following other examples on this site. The issue isn't getting all of one particular element, but finding the path to the specific element I want. For instance, if the page had 5,000 td's, and each of those td's had a child, I would have to figure out which td's child I needed. Maybe I do this by making an array and just spending a LONG time trying to determine which child is the right value i.e. child[3,018]. This seems super inefficient and definitely not the coder way! Trying .select approach gets me empty arrays.

Comment: Does the smaller select I suggested work? It seemed to on the page you linked.

Comment: I tried it and I keep getting a blank array in the console. I'll attach a screen shot in my question if I can... nope, I need 10 reputation points to post an image. It just outputs []

Comment: Have you verified that printing soup shows the whole document?

Comment: Yep! Printing soup pulls up everything.

Comment: @JJThaeler are you still stuck on this? Did you get it working?

Comment: I actually found this to be super helpful https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beautifulsoup/1BbdGf2qQ6Y and it details how to turn an XPath into a target for bs4. If you want to write this up and submit it as an answer I will check it off as the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I've been working with BeautifulSoup a lot lately and thought I'd offer a solution. Hopefully my comments in the code will provide sufficient explanation for each part.

```
# instead of parsing the entire html doc, only parse the division that
# contains ER and IC wait times
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer(id='PageContent'))
```

Let me add that many web scraping efforts involve only extracting a small portion of the html/xml response. The `SoupStrainer` class offers an excellent way to reduce the size of your `soup` objects and hone in on the relevant parts of the html/xml doc.

```
waittimes = []
```

Emergency room wait times are contained in an html `<table>`. Each `<td>` tag within the table contains one row of information for one facility.

```
# isolate the ER wait times in the only <table> in the soup object
ERtimes = soup('table')
# further isolate the data by filtering on the <td> tags
tds = ERtimes[0]('td')

# in this case every other <td> tag contains data. the others contain
# formatting instructions
for td in tds[::2]:
# extract only the text data in the <td> tag using stripped_strings generator
# keep only the facility name, wait time and the timestamp
waittimes.append([str for i, str in enumerate(td.stripped_strings) if i in [0, 2, 3]])
```

Immediate care wait times for all 8 facilities are contained in one `<div>` tag. The parsing is thus handled differently than the ER times.

```
# isolate the IC wait times which are contained in a <div> tag
# find all of the <div> tags but keep the last one which has the data
# for all 8 facilities
ICtimes = soup('div')[-1] 

# once again use the stripped_strings generator to extract the pertinent text data
# however, in this case the data from the 8 facilities are returned into a single list
longlist = [str for str in ICtimes.stripped_strings]
# list comprehension to return the data from the single list into groups of 3
# which are facility name, wait time and timestamp
waittimes.extend([longlist[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0, len(longlist), 3)])
```

Here is what waittimes looks like:

```
In [162]: waittimes
Out[162]: 
[[u'Alexian Brothers Medical Center',u'0 minutes',u'as of 1/7/2016 10:38:37 AM'],
 [u'St. Alexius Medical Center',u'3 HOURS 40 MINS',u'as of 1/6/2016 6:51:11 PM'],
 [u'Addison', u'30 minutes', u'as of 1/7/2016 10:44:44 AM'],
 [u'Elk Grove', u'120 minutes', u'as of 1/7/2016 11:42:22 AM'],
 [u'Bensenville', u'45 mins', u'as of 1/7/2016 10:49:05 AM'],
 [u'Hanover Park', u'15 Mins', u'as of 1/7/2016 11:45:08 AM'],
 [u'Mt. Prospect', u'1 hour', u'as of 1/7/2016 11:22:53 AM'],
 [u'Schaumburg', u'1 hour', u'as of 1/7/2016 11:56:10 AM'],
 [u'Palatine', u'30 minutes', u'as of 1/7/2016 12:06:35 PM']]
```

Of course, I didn't write the routines needed to clean up the data. I focused on extracting the pertinent data and presenting it in a structured format.